# Every day vs everyday?

Tags: grammar

So, in the next phrase:

*«I miss you. That's the hardest thing I've got to deal with **everyday**»*

1. According to that phrase, should it be every day or everyday?
2. Also, what's the difference between these two, could you please give me many examples?

Thank you! ❤️

Answer (score 3):

This dilemma is relatively common among people, it can be slightly confusing at times. Every day means *each day* whereas everyday is an adjective used to describe something that has been/has been seen used every day.

*Everyday*: These are great clothes for everyday use.

*Every day*: I exercise every day in order to remain fit and healthy.

Comment: So is my phrase grammatically correct?

Comment: @Illiana no. If dealing with missing someone is the hardest thing to do, no matter what day it is, then the correct usage is **every day**. In other words, every day is the same in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

"*Everyday*" is an adjective used like "ordinary" or "usual"; it modifies a noun.

"*Every day*" is an adverb used like "ordinarily" or "usually"; it modifies a verb or adjective.

As a simple test, try replacing "everyday" with "ordinary", and "every day" with "ordinarily", and see if it means what you meant to say.

Which one is obviously wrong?:

- «I miss you. That's the hardest thing I've got to deal with *ordinary*» (≡ everyday)
- «I miss you. That's the hardest thing I've got to deal with *ordinarily*» (≡ every day)